# How to Find the Means of an Array, By Counting The Digit Simultaneously

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math

Excuse me all, I want to ask one question, it was bothering me right now. I think it's a quite simple. But i don't know how to solve it. Perhaps you all know about this.

This question is an array like this `[3,4,5]` and the answer is 5

The algorithm to get the answer is by doing this things

[image: 3 4 5 / / 4 5 / 5]

(Every decimal number will be rounds up to the next largest integer)

So the answer that we will get is 5.

---

For other question is like `[8,1,8,8,0]` the output will be 7

[image]

Is there is someone that maybe knows how to solve this, i use javascript for this algorithm.

But still can't finding the way to solve this

Every help would be nice,

thanks

Comment: Note that you introduce a bias by always rounding up to the next integer. Alternating up/down would give a better result generally

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise? It is rather inefficient, O(n^2). Two loops can easily solve it.

Comment: i think the question is how we did add `Math.ceil((3+4)/2) = 4` will be added with `Math.ceil((4+5)/2) = 5` So it will print the `Math.ceil((4+5)/2)` exactly with `5` values

Comment: @Damien what do you mean with two loop. how we get that?

Comment: The first loop would corresponds to the size `new_size`of the new array (from n-1 to 1) and the second would correspond to an index `i` from 0 to `new_size-1`: `arr[i] = (arr[i]+arr[i+1])/2` (I have omitted the `ceil`here for simplicity).

Comment: oh i got it, damn as easy like that. Thank for your help @Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate whoile you have a length greater than one and map a new array of a smaller array.

```js
let array = [8, 1, 8, 8, 0];

console.log(...array);
while (array.length > 1) {
    let l = array[0]
    array = array.slice(1).map(r => {
        let v = Math.ceil((l + r) / 2);
        l = r;
        return v;
    });
    console.log(...array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over an array and continue doing the math until there is only one item in the array. You can do the following,

```js
const getAverageForEachPair = (arr) => {
   if(arr.length ===1) {
      return arr;
   } else {
      let res = [];
      for(let i = 0; i < arr.length -1; i++) {
         res[i] = Math.ceil((arr[i] + arr[i+1])/2);
      }
      return res;
   }
}

let arr = [8,1,8,8,0];

while(arr.length > 1) {
    let line1 = '';
    arr.forEach(item => {
       line1 += (item + '    ');
    });
    
    let line2 = '';
    
    console.log(line1);
    arr = getAverageForEachPair(arr);
    arr.forEach(item => {
        line2 += ' \\ / ';
    });
    console.log(line2);
}

console.log(' '+arr[0]);
```

Comment: thank you @sabbir.alam , it was great answer, actually i just one to get the last value. But you build the great visualization. Thanks